# Copy over data with concatenating few columns together

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my google sheets I have two sheets/tabs.

In Sheet 1 I have below columns

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Phone# | St Address | City | Buzzer# |
| 2 | 123 | Street 1 | Toronto | 564 |
| 3 | 456 | Street 2 | Cambridge |  |
| 4 | 523 | Street 1 | Guelph |  |
| 5 | 412 | Street 1 | Barrie | 985 |

In my sheet 2 I want to copy all these data as below format. I am trying to copy over `column A -> Phone#` Column as is and concatenate `column B | Column C | Column D` columns together with `,`. Where if There is Buzzer number I want to append word Buzzer end of the city name otherwise leave it blank.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Phone# | Complete Address |
| 2 | 123 | Street 1, Toronto, Buzzer 564 |
| 3 | 456 | Street 2, Cambridge |
| 4 | 523 | Street 1, Guelph |
| 5 | 412 | Street 1, Barrie, Buzzer 985 |

And Here is How I have tried to copy over data from Sheet1 to sheet2 and concatenate columns B,C,D together

```
=Query('Sheet1'!A:D,"Select A and CONCATENATE((IF(D<>"",(CONCATENATE("Buzzer-"," ",D,", ")),"")),B,", ",C,", ",D) where A is not null",1)
```

Obviously this didn't work.
Any suggestions or Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a quick sheet with the solution using:

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A2:A12), "",ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet1!A2:A12,ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!B2:B12&", "&Sheet1!C2:C12&", "&Sheet1!D2:D12)})))

The sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E1lBW63CyVJAUmq1okIQgn6-FY82QHt829hpeb0yWxw/edit?usp=sharing